# Spring Security HttpSecurity config for Multiple scenarios

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory, spring-oauth2

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainJWT(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.securityMatchers
            (matcher -> matcher.requestMatchers(request ->
                    request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) != null &&
                            request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION).startsWith("Bearer")));

    http.exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/signout").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .csrf().disable();


    http.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}


@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainLogin(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.apply(AadWebApplicationHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadWebApplication())
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/signout").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .csrf().disable();
    return http.build();
}
```

**Case 1** : Get request `/login` --> Redirect to Active Directory(Oauth) login(Expected) --> Filter works because of filterChainLogin Bean

**Case 2**: POST Request( With Bearer token) `/api/getuser` --> Works (Expected) --> Filter works because of filterChainJWT Bean

**Case 3**: POST Request( Without Bearer token) `/api/getuser` --> Redirect to Active Directory login (Not expected)

How can I make it work for Case 3? My expectation is Case 3 should show 401/403(Forbidden) without Bearer instead redirect to Active directory Login (Oauth)

Comment: Have you got to try using AntMatchers in this scenario: `.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize - authorize
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/signout").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .csrf().disable();   ...`

Comment: *Redirect to Active Directory login (Not expected)* Whym is that unexpected. You only apply your first configuration, if the `Bearer` exists,. If you want to apply your first configuration also in this situation, so you have to extend the matcher.

Comment: @dur Can you help me on this ? Do i need to write one more bean ? New marcher?

Comment: @kavyaS is there any difference between antMatcher vs requestMatcher?